# Reading string into struct from binary file using fread(): Error

Tags: c

In populating an array of structs from a binary file using fread(), the first half of the array prints correctly using printf(), while the latter half prints nulls for the string.

The input string (`model`) is stated to NOT contain "non-readable characters" such as '\t', '\n' or '\0'. By that I'm assuming it's necessary to add a terminating null byte to the string.

My so-far 2-day research seems to support the following idea: Allocate memory for the string + 1 byte, read input string into struct, and tack on a '\0' in the extra byte:

```
struct Router {
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned char flag;
    unsigned char len;
    char *model;
    Router *links;
    int index;
};

typedef struct Router Router;

Router *routers;

// ...

bool createRouters() {

    routers = calloc(sizeof(Router), count); // checked: count == 50, space is sufficient!

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Router *r = &routers[i];

        unsigned char endbyte;

        fread(&r->id, 4, 1, binary);
        fread(&r->flag, 1, 1, binary);
        fread(&r->len, 1, 1, binary);

        r->model = calloc(r->len + 1, 1);

        fread(r->model, 1, r->len, binary);

        *(r->model + r->len) = '\0';

        fread(&endbyte, 1, 1, binary);

        r->links = malloc(sizeof(Router) * 10);
        r->index = -1;

        if (endbyte != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        printf("%d: %s (0x%x)\n", r->id, r->model, r->flag);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Binary input file spec:

- Router id, `unsigned int`
- A flag, `unsigned char`
- Length of model string, `unsigned char`
- Model, `char[]` (containing no "non-readable characters")
- "1 byte of value 0"

Output:

```
Creating routers...
0: Cisco d70 (0x43)
1: Juniper y400k (0x95)
2: Cisco q100 (0xb4)
3: Juniper x100z (0xd4)
4: D-Link k9000n (0xd6)
5: Cisco v400 (0x82)
6: Netgear c4 (0x7)
7: Linksys l700 (0xf1)
8: D-Link x50 (0xf3)
9: D-Link p4000p (0x76)
10: ZyXEL y6000 (0x52)
11: Cisco s300t (0x94)
12: Juniper d10r (0x54)
13: D-Link r8000x (0xe7)
14: ZyXEL x90f (0x24)
15: Juniper s9h (0x63)
16: D-Link v5 (0x57)
17: Juniper d900r (0xe7)
18: D-Link j50g (0x87)
19: D-Link i9y (0x82)
20: D-Link v60 (0xe3)
21: Juniper h10a (0x47)
22: ZyXEL w50 (0x27)
23: Juniper s20 (0x27)
24: Netgear p10m (0x75)
25: D-Link y5o (0x34)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
0:  (0x0)
```

Some attempted variations:

- Not tacking on the terminating null byte ("done automatically by fread()? Covered by null byte in input block?")
- Switching places of `r->len` and `1` in `fread(r->model, r->len, 1, binary)`
- Declaring receiving struct field as array instead of pointer
- malloc() vs. calloc()
- Reading input into temporary variables first

Some of these variations have printed garbage for the strings instead of nulls.

It is perhaps also worth noting that the issue "showed up" at some point, and I was not able to revert the code to a working state. Tried deleting the .exe-file as if to clean the environment, but I suspect that everything is clean with each compile in C, I don't know.

I'm new to C and I really want to understand what is going on here. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really, really looks like you are actually reading those last zeroes (it's not EOF nor does it look like a memory overwrite). Is it possible an earlier (failed) attempt wrote them into your data file? Use a hex editor to verify; search for that last string and check what should be next.

Comment: Input file is unchanged according to the hex editor.

Comment: All calls `fread()` lack error checking.  You want to test the value returned by `fread()`.

Comment: Can you upload that data file somewhere so we can try for ourselves?

Comment: Sure! Here it is, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MDso01bcdQT741Vtgav1RVlz3ff0PWhC

Comment: Okay, thanks. I already created one from your data and apart from the first 'count' value it seems equal. The bad news is, your reading routine works without changes. Your problem lies elsewhere – likely some UB in an entirely other part. Try running under `valgrind` to flush it out.

Comment: ... Have to ask. Are you *sure* this is your entire reading routine? I find lots of extra data at the end of the file; are those to be filled in to the `links` member of your `Router`? If you do that using another routine, you may be overwriting the data in the table. (By extension, it also means that the output you show is not THE output, as written by THIS routine.)

Comment: Exactly, those data are read into `links` in another method. I did suspect that some local settings on my end was causing this, as I seem to be getting some inconsistent result. In fact I was just enabling linux subsystem here to check with valgrind. Thanks a million for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: I'm sorry - what is UB? Edit: Oh - undefined behavior.

Comment: Just ran it on Windows Linux Subsystem and it worked. Thanks again for your input! :-) Stay safe

Comment: It's easier to write `r->model[r->len] = '\0';` than to write `*(r->model + r->len) = '\0';`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: ah, the safe old belt-and-suspenders approach. When using `calloc`, [the memory is set to zero](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc).

Comment: @usr2564301 — yes, that too, so the assignment isn't necessary.  If it's written, the subscript notation is still cleaner, but it doesn't need to be written when the memory is allocated with `calloc()`.  OTOH, there isn't much sense in using `calloc()` if you know you're about to overwrite all but one of the zero bytes with non-zero bytes, so using `malloc()` instead of `calloc()` and retaining the assignment (but using subscript notation) is reasonably sensible.